# Is it possible to make a card divider?

Tags: trello

I am trying to turn Trello to look like my whiteboard but I got stuck.

What I want to do is put 3 colleagues on a Trello board where each list will represent 1 colleague. Then I would add tasks via cards. Some tasks are ongoing and some are future ones and **I would like to visually divide ongoing from future tasks**.

Like this image:

[image]

Is this possible in Trello? To colourize the card fully, not just upper left corner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have 3 suggestions that may fit your needs in a slightly different way:

1. Work with 6 columns: 3 colleagues x (ongoing + future)
2. Define 2 users per colleague: one (say, `A`) for ongoing tasks and another (say, `future_A`) for the future tasks. Each user will have a different color dot.
3. Add a virtual card to separate ongoing tasks (above this card) from future tasks (below the card). You can assign this task to a virtual person just to mark it with a different color.

Comment: point 1 - I tried this a while ago and it did not work well. too many cards. especially if we hire another person for 1 project

Comment: point 2 - well wanted to do it without having to attach users. we tried it before and to be frank everyone hated updating their account. this way we create one account and put it in full screen on an old pc attached to a projector and have a real Canban board.

Comment: I understand your reservations about these options. I added a 3rd suggestion that might better fit your needs.

Comment: LOL I did the 3rd thing mylsef before :). I will mark this as an answer anyway

Comment: The term Swimlanes is used in the context of the Kanban visual methodology to describe different horizontal lanes with vertical columns designated TODO, in progress, Done, etc. In kanbanflow, for example, [swimlanes](https://kanbanflow.com/img/press/screenshots/Swimlanes.png) are a premium feature. As far as I know it is not implemented in Trello.

Comment: The virtual card is what I've been doing lately. I've taken  to using "divider" cards on TODO columns, e.g. ********* High Priority ************. I'd love this to be built into Trello.

Answer (score 3):

Another thing you can do is use card labels to signify the distinction between ongoing and future.  Add the green label for all of the ongoing cards, and the red label for all of the future ones.  The labels do display on the main board, which can give you that visual representation.

Also, if you want to enhance the visual representation of those colors, you can download a browser plugin such as [Beautify for Trello](http://www.mindofmoses.com/blog/customize-your-trello-boards-with-beautify) to make the whole face of the card the color of the label.

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange! Great answer, I have edited it so that the link to Beautify is textified.

Answer (score 1):

Or try this:  ▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬

Comment: Awesome, it looks very good!

Answer (score 1):

Trello now officially supports having divider cards (though they can't have labels yet).

## How to add a card with a divider

Create a card with `---` as the title:

[image]

Source: https://twitter.com/trello/status/1193893152383471616

Answer (score 0):

I've got dividers cards in my lists like this:

> ▲ — Prioritised (URGENT) — ▲

And some tags as well, like this:

> ● —— 2.17.30 —— ●

I find the [unicode](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/25A0-25FF) shapes and lines help make the "divider" card stand out a bit more.